# Is there a way to update input fields to have a red border around them when value is missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I have a state object with initial value and error state which is an empty array.

```
const [values,setValues] = useState([
  question: "",
  topic: "",
  age: "",
  gender: "",
  consent: false,
]];

const [error,setError] useState([]);
```

I click a button that fires off a validation function:

```
let validate = () => {

 const { age, gender, topic, consent } = values;
 let validationErrors = [];

  if (!age) {
   let ageError = { name: "Age" };
   validationErrors.push(ageError);
  }
  If (!gender) {
   let genderError = { name: "Gender" };
   validationErrors.push(genderError);
  }
  if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
   setError(validationErrors);
  } else {
     setError([]);
     return true;
  }
```

How do I now for example add a class to each field that are missing a value when button is clicked.

here is the jsx for one of my inputs:

```
 <select
   value={values.topic}
   name="topic"
   onChange={handleInputChange}
    >
      <option value="">Velg tema</option>
      {categories.nodes.map(topic => (
      <option key={topic._id} value={topic._id}>
        {topic.title}
      </option>
     ))}
  </select>
```

I have tried to use

```
 className={values.gender ? "" : "gend"}
```

and that gend is a class with a red border.

Comment: can you also add your jsx code also

Comment: @ShubhamVerma added my topic input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created one small poc. Ideally you should handle this using some form library  like [formik](https://formik.org/). Here is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    question: "",
    topic: "",
    age: "",
    gender: "",
    consent: false
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if (error.includes(name)) {
      setError(error.filter((e) => e !== name));
    }
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const { question, topic } = values; //can add rest according to your requirement
    const errorList = [];
    if (!question) {
      errorList.push("question");
    }
    if (!topic) {
      errorList.push("topic");
    }
    console.log(errorList);
    setError(errorList);
  };
  console.log(error);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="question"
          name="question"
          value={values.question}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          className={error.includes("question") ? "error" : ""}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="topic"
          name="topic"
          value={values.topic}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          className={error.includes("topic") ? "error" : ""}
        />
      </div>

      <select value={values.topic} name="topic" onChange={handleInputChange}>
        <option value="">Velg tema</option>
      </select>

      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Validate</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cohen-61xru?file=/src/App.js:0-1589

Answer (score 0):

For each input in your JSX, add this attribute:

```
className={classNames('yourClass', {error: !age})} //example for age input
```

And in your **CSS** add class **error**:

```
.error {
   border: red solid 1px;
}
```

So you need to install **classNames** module, you can learn about classNames from here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Comment: I don't think I need to use a classname library. It should work by using conditional rendering with ternary operator

Comment: I think its  easy to work with classnames than using conditional rendering. With ternary operator you have to add className={error.includes("question") ? "error" : ""}, with classNames you have to  add className={{error: error.includes("question")}}, and JSX is syntactic sugar, you don't have to complicate things.

Comment: That is true. I will consider it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achive this

```
let validate = () => {
    const { age, gender, topic, consent } = values;

    let validationErrors = [];

    if (!age) {
        let ageError = { name: "Alder" };
        validationErrors.push(ageError);
        document.getElementsById('name').style.borderColor = "red";
    }

    If(!gender) {
        let genderError = { name: "Kjønn" };
        validationErrors.push(genderError);
        document.getElementsById('gender').style.borderColor = "red";
    }

    if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
        setError(validationErrors);
    } else {
        setError([]);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think manipulating the dom directly the react way. Maybe I can use ref